# Why isn't this trigger good?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

The problem is as follows: a maximum of 50 employees is allowed in any department

My teacher said that the trigger below isn't the solution but I didn't catch the explanation, so he presented us another solution using a row-level trigger and packages (because of mutation).

What is the scenario in which the trigger below doesn't behave the intended way? I really can't think of one.

Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pb10_trp AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF department_id ON employees
DECLARE
    nr   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        MAX(COUNT(employee_id) )
    INTO
        nr
    FROM
        employees
    GROUP BY
        department_id;

    IF
        nr > 50
    THEN
        raise_application_error(-20456,'Too many employees!');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: can you provide the teachers trigger so we can compare?

Comment: This will check after the row is inserted. Instead of after trigger use before and check for existing count = 50

Comment: What if two sessions insert the 50th member of a department simultaneously? Each will get a count of 50 - since they can't see each others uncommitted data - but after both inserts commit there will be 51. It would be interesting to see your teacher's approach. (Also, why `max()`?)

Comment: @Alex Poole: This is an after statement trigger. `MAX` gets the maximum count of all department counts. Oracle allows this shortcut, so we don't need a derived table.

Comment: @Alex Poole: I suppose, as this trigger fires at commit, that the scenario you describe is not possible. It would mean that Oracle executes one on-commit trigger, then the other, then the first commit, then the other. I don't think this can happen; it will always be on-commit trigger, then its commit. **To me this trigger looks like the perfect solution for the given problem.**

Comment: I'd say a general principle is that any code which makes an update conditional on the results of a select, should make the select first and hold the appropriate lock on the select until (as the case may be) the update has completed successfully.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, but by your own logic, if the commits are not finalised until after the triggers, then when two concurrent transactions are ongoing, both inserting into `employees`, neither is guaranteed to see the other's update (and its effect on the number of employees) during the execution of the trigger.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I’d realised why the max was there, having noticed it was getting the highest count across any department;  then forgot and asked about it anyway <sigh> But does the end of the statement really imply end of transaction? A subsequent statement in the same transaction won’t see the effects of the trigger?

Comment: It's not a solution to read uncommitted rows either, because that will mean rows will be read (or not read, in the case of concurrent deletes) which may later be rolled back, and there is still a race condition in that both transactions may read each other's uncommitted rows, and both will consequently fail (when one ought to have succeeded).

Comment: @Steve ~ Oracle doesn’t let you read uncomitted data from other sessions.

Comment: Statement triggers, as the one you posted, are a logically correct answer to the problem you stated. As far as I know, the knock on statement triggers is inefficiency. You may only insert one new employee in one department, but the statement trigger still must aggregate and count for ALL departments. What was the teacher's explanation - and what did she mean by "this isn't the solution"? You can ask the teacher after class, or at office hours, etc. - no shame in that.

Comment: @AlexPoole, fair one! I'm more accustomed to SQL Server, and just trying to cover all bases. Concurrency control is one of the most frequent spike pits with databases. Transactions only offer the guarantee that changes will succeed atomically as a set or not at all. They do not guarantee that, where changes are programmed to be conditional on a particular state, that state will not change after the condition is evaluated but before the end of the transaction. The latter guarantee is only offered at the statement level, not in relation to a series of statements.

Comment: ...locking hints have to be used in order to guarantee that the state which was previously read (in a separate statement) to support a conditional update, will not be changed before the transaction is committed.

Comment: For anyone interested in evidence from testing, consider the following link, which is considering the case where an insert/update decision is conditional on a previous read: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, but that's my point, the trigger follows an insert or update. In this particular case, unless the isolation level itself is set to serializable (which is not the default), the trigger is vulnerable to the fact that the exclusive lock on the table will be released before the trigger fires, allowing another concurrent transaction to step in and update it (with no guarantee of when those updates will be committed), but the results seen by the select in one transaction will not include the other transactions' uncommitted updates (and vice versa). The trigger may pass for both.

Comment: ...in this particular case, serializable isolation will protect the trigger (because it will hold the exclusive lock from the moment of update until commit time after the trigger, preventing any other concurrent transaction proceeding with its update and into its own trigger). But serializable isolation is not currently enforced by the trigger itself (it doesn't check for it, and reject the transaction automatically if it is not set).

Comment: Sorry @Steve and the others, I confused after-statement triggers with the concept of deferred constraints. There are no on-commit triggers in Oracle. So I was plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete case of the problem is as follows:
  - the "no more than 50 employees per department" can be added later in the table

Having this said, the provided solution is not correct because if a department has more than 50 employees when this trigger is enabled, no one can execute insert or update actions on the table anymore.

Eg:

1. Department 1 has 51 employees and department 2 has 3 employees.
2. User A inserts 2 employees in department 2, so the total number of employees would become 5.
3. Trigger raises error, even though user A did not do anything wrong.

Comment: The man, the myth, the legend (even though the 'correctness' seems to be a matter of subjectivity)

Comment: @TomaRadu, for real brownie points, I'd make the point about locking to your teacher! The risk of the table starting with more than 50 employees in any department before the trigger is enabled is the least of the concerns, because even if the table is started correctly, there is a risk due to inadequate concurrency control that it will acquire more than 50 employees per department even *after* the trigger is enabled (even if the trigger is rejigged to only check the specific departments affected by its own transaction).

Comment: I think it's only natural to assume the table does not have more than 50 employees per Department, yet. Otherwise we could just count, see it's more than 50, report that the table data already violates the rule and be done, because we cannot guarantee a limit of 50 employees per department anymore. So this answer doesn't really help here in my opinion.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Actually, that's the reasoning of my teacher, too. I completely agree with you, though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I agree. Any trigger that is designed to enforce a constraint, can always fall victim to the fact that constraints have already been violated before it was enabled, if the person enabling the trigger does not check for the case - and there is no way of writing a trigger that does not have this vulnerability.

Comment: Setting the isolation level to serializable will not solve the problem

Comment: I think essentially your teacher may be right, in that you have to control the transaction through a "Table API" for want of a better term. In other words, a package that controls the DML to the employees table.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Ideally, constraints like this are part of the table design; the trigger is written and compiled right after table creation, before any data is inserted. And if this is a constraint that the business has added after some time, the departments that already have more than 50 employees must be handled. Either they are downsized, or if a list of exceptions is agreed upon, then that can be easily reflected in the trigger code: select the max over departments not in the exception list. Either way, the statement trigger approach is correct (possibly with this small change).

Comment: Ignore the issue about the trigger being added after the rows are inserted. The trigger will still not work because of the concurrent access that Alex mentioned earlier